# How to get subfolder from Amazon S3 using R?

Tags: r, amazon-s3

Unfortunately, its diffucult to create a reproducible example. I would like to get some data `john.csv` which is save on a `aws.s3` bucket:

Bucket structure with different subfolders:

```
my_bucket/company
my_bucket/player
my_bucket/score
my_bucket/results/game/john.csv

library(aws.s3)
```

from [Github](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3)

```
# Define credentials
Sys.setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "",
           "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "",
           "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "")



# get file from S3
my_bucket<- get_bucket(bucket = 'my_bucket')
```

That generates a list with only elements from  `my_bucket/company`. How can I get the `john.csv` from a subfolder?

Comment: S3 doesn't have directories, it's a flat file structure where `/` symbols in key names are represented as directories in the web interface. To get `john.csv`, you need to do: `get_object(object = "results/game/john.csv", bucket = "my_bucket")`. `get_bucket()` will list all objects, though they may be paginated if you have >1000 objects in the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3/blob/master/README.Rmd), you need to call `get_object()`:

```
# get file as raw vector
raw.vector <- get_object("john.csv", bucket = "my_bucket")
```

The readme file didn't give any implementation details, but presumably it is doing a path search for objects at the end of the path.  I didn't see anything listed which does a general path search based on an input string.